# Vector spaces $v$ and $w$ are finite dimensional prove that $v×w$ is also finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

If two vector spaces $v$ and $w$ are finite dimensional,how do we prove that $v×w$ is also finite dimensional.How do we express $dim(v×w)$ in terms of $dim(v)$ and $dim(w)$

Comment: Its the sum of dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$ (dimension $n$) and let $\{w_1, w_2, ..., w_m\}$ a basis for $W$ (dimension $m$).

It's not hard to show that $\{(v_1, 0), (v_2, 0), ..., (v_n,0), (0, w_1), (0, w_2), ..., (0, w_m) \}$ is a basis for $V \times W$, since those vectors are linearly independent and you can write any vector in $V \times W$ as a linear combination of those.

That basis has $n+m$ elements, which makes $\dim(V \times W)=n+m$.

Long story short, $\dim (V \times W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W)$.